# Caching query results on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I started using Google App Engine 3 months ago and I have a question regarding Python on [memcaching](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/).
I try to describe my problem as best as I can.

I use [ndb (App Engine Datastore)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/storage#app_engine_datastore) and I have a "table" of entities like this:

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
    dateInsert = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)              # Inserting date
    notes = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)                         # event notes
    geohash = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)                       # Coordinates geohash 
    eventLatitude = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed=True, required=True)    # self explanatory
    eventLongitude = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed=True, required=True)   # self explanatory
```

Client side (with a mobile app for example) a user can store in datastore an event in specified coordinates.
Those inserted events are visible of course by mobile app (on the map) and on a website.
Right now to retrieve stored events, client calls a web method that search events near a given location:

```
class getEvents(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #blablabla get passed parameters
        #[...]

        # hMinPos and hMaxPos are hashed coordinates passed by client + X meters. 
        # In this way I can filter stored events in a precise bounding box.
        # For example, I can get events near my location in a box of 5000 meters
        qryEvent = Event.query(ndb.AND(Event.geohash >= hMinPos, Event.geohash <= hMaxPos))
        events = qryEvent.fetch(1000)
```

Then I have to fetch every result with a loop cycle to create a JSON to store in a list and return it to the client.
So it is

```
for event in events:
    #do my stuff
```

Everything is working fine, but the big problem are useless read operations EVERY single time I call that method. 
I mean, every time method gets called, it fetches same events than other clients request or worst, same events than previous request by same client (if I move by 50meters and I make a client request, events are same as previous request ad 99%).
This will take quota usage and read operations over-quota very soon.
I think I should use `memcache` to store fetched events and read them in the memcache before make a read from datastore, but I have no idea to implement it with my structure.

My idea was to use geohash as a memcache key, but I can't iterate through cached elements, I can only make a precise get on a given key so my solution is not applicable (I can't make a direct access to memcache with a key, I need to iterate in memcache elements to find event that fits my coordinate-range request). 
Someone has a hint or a suggestion?

Comment: Did you know ndb already does [two levels of caching](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache)?  Are you more worried about the queries or the fetching of the entities?  I'd recommend taking a look at [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-trace/) to see what RPCs are going to hit you most.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Right now my biggest problem is to limit reads from datastore so I'm worried about entities fetching..anyway I take a look at provided links!

Comment: Caching with ndb doesn't occur with queries.  Only with get's.  You could adopt a few strategies.  Cache the query results once converted to json your self or do a keys only query and the do a get_multi and let ndb cache the items for you.

Comment: Any caching you do yourself at the JSON result level means you will need to then consider cache invalidation strategies, which will be dependent on how accurate you need the info and how frequent you expect new points of interest to be added that match the query.

Comment: Exactly, I know this. My solution should be to fetch a keys_only from db and then look in the cache. If some key are not in the cache I will do a query_multi on db with missing keys, then I wil add them in cache. Return list will (should) be sum of cached and retrieved from database.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks for clarifying - I had wrongly interpreted the docs when they say *if any individual result is in the in-context cache, it is used in place of the value retrieved from the Datastore query*.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 solutions:

1) Store in memcached the information of smaller boxes (e.g. 100 meters long), with a latitude-longitude identifier. You could request from ndb a big box of e.g. 5500 meters long, and save the information of all the contained small boxes in memcached. When the user moves 50, 100 or 400 meters, you'll be able to give her an answer with memcached data, and if someone is near that place (within 500 meters), same thing will happen.

2) You could use ElasticSearch, specifically the [Geo Distance Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html). With it, you can filter `"documents that include only hits that exists within a specific distance from a geo point"`.

Note: If *getEvents* return events in a box of 5000 meters, maybe you shouldn't trigger a new request when moving 50 meters, but a longer distance.